# What is the best way to set a collation in Informix IDS?

Tags: informix

I'm administrating a informix IDS DBMS in Argentina. We speak spanish, and the traditional ASCII caracter Set of Informix doesn't fit our needs.

I've been fooling around, and make it work with the DB_LOCALE variable. But i've seen some other call CLIENT_LOCALE and SERVER_LOCALE. Should i use them? Is it enough with DB_LOCALE

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mainly need to set CLIENT_LOCALE and DB_LOCALE - to es_es.8859-1 or something similar (maybe es_ar.8859-1, but you would probably need to get the ILS International Language Supplement to get that, assuming it is available at all).

The server locale controls the language used when the server reports errors.  Some of the messages in the server log files would be given in Spanish rather than English.

The DB_LOCALE controls how the data is sorted in the database in indexes.  It is most critical when the database is created; if it is not set, the database will be assumed to be in US English (American).  You should normally set DB_LOCALE when accessing the database too, though it isn't quite as critical.  The CLIENT_LOCALE should be set too.  Usually, these values are the same.  Sometimes, though, you have a Windows client running using a Microsoft code page for Spanish (CP 1252, I think) and a Unix server using 8859-1 or perhaps 8859-15.  In those cases, the GLS (Global Language Support) library will automatically take care of codeset conversion for you.